# Bootstrap loading spinner at right side of ul li

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to place a Bootstrap loading spinner on the right side of a ui li and have the text "Keywords" on the left side of the ui li.

I have the following html code

```
<ul class="list-group" id="my-list">
   <li class="list-group-item active" aria-current="true">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col float-left">Keywords</div>
         <div class="col spinner-border spinner-border-sm float-right" role="status">
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

The spinner is showing up as two lines spinning instead of a spinning circle.

[image]

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styling of the `.col` is conflicting with the `spinner-border` class.
Moving the [spinner](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/spinners/) as a child under `.col` container loads the spinner correctly.

Added `.visually-hidden` to hide sr-only text.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-group" id="my-list">
   <li class="list-group-item active" aria-current="true">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col float-left">Keywords</div>
         <div class="col float-right">
           <div class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status">
             <span class="sr-only visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**[UPDATE]**

Above solution does not right align the loader. Utilizing [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/) `.d-flex` to right align with `justify-content-end` and vertically align with `.align-items-center`.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-group" id="my-list">
  <li class="list-group-item active" aria-current="true">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-10">Keywords</div>
      
      <div class="col-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
        <div class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status">
          <span class="sr-only visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```